# SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to install Management Studio by itself, and if so, is there a separate download/install exe for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Management Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C243A5AE-4BD1-4E3D-94B8-5A0F62BF7796&displaylang=en)

and 2008 added:

[Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Management Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=08E52AC2-1D62-45F6-9A4A-4B76A8564A2B&displaylang=en)

Comment: This page helped me: http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/InstallOptions.aspx

Comment: @Richard Morgan nice one! very useful as for me

Comment: "Express"; what are the differences between the express edition of management studio and the other(s)?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, use custom install and chose not to install the database engine.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that there is one installation, but you can pick the management tools (and not install a server).

BTW - the 2008 installer takes forever and is way more complicated than the 2005 installer.

Comment: It can take several passes in the installer, and most will not show any difference to the user so it is difficult to tell if you are making progress when installing.

Answer (score 3):

You can get [Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 RTM - Management Studio Express here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=56AD557C-03E6-4369-9C1D-E81B33D8026B&displaylang=en&displaylang=en).

Answer (score 2):

I believe that if you install SQL Server Management Express, you can't manage all the objects you can in the version you get from installing from the media. For example, you can't manage integration services or analysis services with management express.

The only way I've ever been able to install it is from the media; but like a previous post mentions, you don't have to install the database engine.

It's confusing for new DBAs that's for sure. I spent a significant amount of time trying to find a "SSMS.msi" on microsoft's website before I figured out it was on the media, and could be installed without installing the database engine; though you have to go to "install SQL Server Stand-alone" to get to it.

Fortunately, I'm still having a hard time trying to keep the server version and all the developers that need SSMS on the same version. If anyone knows of a way to make an .MSI (or download) one that contains all the correct versions of A.S./S.S.I.S/Database Engine I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for RQDQ. For 2008 I think you need 3.5 .Net Framework also. And yes it takes forever doing all kinds of validations.

Answer (score 0):

you can download management studio by itself, but when you install Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2, management studio is also installed

Answer (score 0):

use below link in order to download  SQL Server Management Studio
https://download.microsoft.com/download/7/7/3/7738e337-ed99-40ea-b8ae-f639162c83c3/SSMS-Setup-ENU.exe

after downloading the exe file follow the steps

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35804373)